# Implication of deleting an /etc/crypttab entry

Tags: linux, partition, kde, lvm

On Arch Linux, I setup an encrypted partition on an LVM volume using KDE Partition Manager.

I lost the password to that partition and I deleted the partion using KDE.

Thereafter the boot process freezed and never reached the login prompt.

I restored from a partition backup and all ran fine.

Now on I get a prompt before login requesting a password which I can skip pressing enter a few times.

`/etc/crypttab` contains an entry to that partition however `/etc/fstab` does not.

Is it an expected behavior for an `/etc/crypttab` entry pointing to an absent volume to freeze the boot process?

I am trying to figure out if the entry was the likely cause of the boot up issue and if I can safely delete the entry and the partition.

The LVM volume is not encrypted.

edit : on Arch use `mkinitcpio -P` to regenerate initramfs

Answer (score 5):

Entries in `/etc/crypttab` works similarly to `/etc/fstab`: if the device listed there is not present, the boot process will try to wait for it and after some time the boot process will fail. It shouldn't freeze, after the timeout you should be switched to shell. If you want to prevent this, you can always add the `nofail` option:

> ```
>    nofail
>       This device will not be a hard dependency of cryptsetup.target.
>       It'll still be pulled in and started, but the system will not wait 
>       for the device to show up and be unlocked, and boot will not fail 
>       if this is unsuccessful. Note that other units that depend on the unlocked 
>       device may still fail. In particular, if the device is used for a mount
>       point, point itself also needs to have the nofail option, or the boot will
>       fail if the device is not unlocked successfully.
> ```

If the encrypted device no longer exists (so it's not just temporarily missing) you can remove it from `/etc/crypttab`, but you also need to regenerate initramfs after that. You didn't say what distribution you use, on Ubuntu you'd use `update-initramfs -u` on Fedora `dracut --regenerate-all`

Comment: Thanks, I use Arch.

Comment: Arch's (default?) initramfs creation/update command seems to be `mkinitcpio`. [More about it in the ArchWiki.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/mkinitcpio)